# Count every nth block of rows and cells

Tags: google-sheets

Given I have the following sheet data

[image]

What I'm trying to do is count the amount of times `Yes` appears in each **column**.

So, I'm looking for something like

```
Header 1: 
  B: 1
  C: 1
  D: 0
Header 2: 
  B: 1
  C: 4
  D: 1
Header 3: 
  B: 2
  C: 1
  D: 0
```

I've tried looking at using `MOD` and with the formula

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MOD((ROW(B1:B14)), 5))
```

I can get the index, then maybe do some offset? The above formula prints

```
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
0
1
2
3
4
```

I'm not too sure where to go from here though.

Desired output

[image]

**EDIT**

Based on the accepted answer, I amended the formula slightly. This was because the cell in A wasn't guaranteed to be empty if it wasn't a header, so I used a `REGEXMATCH`

```
=
ArrayFormula(
  query(
    {
      if(mod(row('Runs 93 - 300'!H:H), 14) = 0, 
        "",
        vlookup(row('Runs 93 - 300'!H:H), {
          if(regexmatch('Runs 93 - 300'!H:H, "RUN #\d+"), row('Runs 93 - 300'!H:H)),
          'Runs 93 - 300'!H:H
        }, 2)
      ),
      if('Runs 93 - 300'!M:Q="Yes",1,)
    },
    "select Col1,count(Col2),count(Col3),count(Col4),count(Col5), count(Col6) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2) '',count(Col3) '',count(Col4) '', count(Col5) '', count(Col6) ''"
  )
)
```

This does make the first cell in the formula output `#RUN 300 #RUN 300` but I can accept that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Vlookup to copy the header down through the rows that are blank in column 1, then use a Group By query to do the counts:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({if(mod(row(A:A),5)=0,"",vlookup(row(A:A),{if(A:A<>"",row(A:A)),A:A},2)),if(B:D="Yes",1,)},"select Col1,count(Col2),count(Col3),count(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2) '',count(Col3) '',count(Col4) ''"))
```

[image]

You could avoid doing a Vlookup on every row (or rather four out of five rows) by limiting it to the rows where the data is:

```
=ArrayFormula(query({if(row(A:A)>counta(A:A)*5,"",vlookup(row(A:A),{if(A:A<>"",row(A:A)),A:A},2)),if(B:D="Yes",1,)},"select Col1,count(Col2),count(Col3),count(Col4) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2) '',count(Col3) '',count(Col4) ''"))
```

Comment: This works, thanks. It's a bit slow for a dataset of 200 rows (and I plan to add more) so I may have to look at how I'm structuring the data.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you have the headers in column A? Seems like you could structure it to where Header 1 is in cell A1, Header 2 is in cell B1, Header 3 is in cell C1, and then the Yes's and No's that pertain to each of those headers could be placed in those respective columns.

Comment: OK, just wondering if it can be speeded up a bit. It does copy the headers right down through the sheet at the moment so that part of it could be made more efficient.

Comment: My reason for the header not being above each thing is because the header is for a bigger block of data. This is just one section of the data that I wanted to glean and attach to that header

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too:

```
={filter(A:A,A:A<>""),index(transpose(len(array_constrain(trim(RegexReplace(split(transpose(query(B:D,,9^9)),"  ",0),"No|\s",)),9^9,3))/3))}
```

[image]